# Appium XCUITest - iOS 10 Tests Are Running Very Slow

Tags: mobile, appium, ios10, ios-ui-automation

Environment:
Appium: 1.6.3
Xcode: 8.1
iOS device version: 10.1

Tests running using Appium XCUITest is very slow

findelement by xpath take very very long time.

is there any way to make it fast?

Comment: Have you tried finding the elements via ID or Accessibility ID? It should be faster that way.

Comment: In my app , I have to use Xpaths majorly as most of the elements can not be located using Accessibility ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It's slow.

Appium version 1.6.3 is a beta version and under test, so you can report bugs related to it on github. There is nothing you can do it to speed it up.

Comment: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7591 opened new issue in GitHub..